# Generate sample from poisson distribution with fixed sum

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, python, poisson-distribution

I want to generate a random sample of size n from poisson distribution with parameter l but the sum of these samples should be equals to some number say y. Is there any way to achieve this? i dont want to generate n-1 samples and subtract the sum of these from y.

Answer (score 15):

Since
$$(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\sim\mathbb P(Y_1=y_1,\ldots,Y_n=y_n)=\dfrac{\lambda^S\exp\{-\lambda\}}{y_1!\cdots y_n!}$$
when $$s=y_1+\cdots+y_n$$
the conditional pmf of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$  given $S=s$ is
$$\mathbb P(Y_1=y_1,\ldots,Y_n=y_n|S=s)\propto\dfrac{1}{y_1!\cdots y_n!}\mathbb I_{y_1+\cdots+y_n=s}$$
This corresponds to a Multinomial $\mathcal M(n,s,1/n)$ distribution, whose simulation is given in [Henry's response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/618639/7224).

Comment: Congrats on 100k reputation coming soon :)

Comment: @RichardHardy: I just noticed..!

Comment: A shout out for @Xi'an for the feat. The community is indebted for your contribution. Any other day, would have made a congratulatory post (but now it is discouraged). You have been mentioned in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63791077#63791077) too. Best wishes and we are looking for many years of your contributions ahead.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods: Thank you for your kind words.

Answer (score 10):

When conditioning on the sum $y$ the Poisson parameter becomes irrelevant, so you in effect want to sample from a multinomial distribution, but may find it easier to do binomial samples:

1. Start with $y$ and $n$
2. Sample a single $x_{i}$ from $\text{Bin}(y_{i}, \frac1{n_{i}})$
3. Move forward by letting $y_{i+1}=y_i-x_i$ and $n_{i+1}=n_i-1$ and repeat 2

As an alternative approach,

- Generate $y$ values uniformly from $[0,n)$
- Count the number in each of $[0,1)$, in $[1,2)$, etc. up to $[n-1,n)$

---

In fact you could just sample $y$ times uniformly with replacement from $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$  (or from  $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ if you think that way) and see how often you get each of the $n$ values.  As an example in R:

```
set.seed(2023)
y <- 40
n <- 10
table(factor(sample(n, y, replace=TRUE), levels=1:n))
```

gives

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 2  6  2  5  5  0  6  7  5  2
```

and the second row is what you want