# Generate sample from negative binomial distribution with fixed sum

Tags: r, simulation, negative-binomial-distribution

Building on this recent post [Generate sample from poisson distribution with fixed sum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618636/generate-sample-from-poisson-distribution-with-fixed-sum) answered by @Henry and @Xi'an, how could we similarly go about generating *n* random samples from a negative binomial distribution with a fixed sum (*y*) and a known size parameter in R?

I imagine that there might be a way to adapt the answers given in the post by using the `prob` argument of `sample` to capture the overdispersion, but I wouldn't know how to implement it!

Comment: The negative binomial distribution is connected with the Poisson distribution when the Poisson parameter is itself a random variable with Gamma distribution.

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an - I've been playing with that a bit. My problem is how I conceptually link that (i.e. different amounts of overdispersion, or different shaped gamma distibutions for lambda) with the multinomial solution provided in the original post above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've had a go at implementing this, inspired by the comment from @Xi'an above. It seems to generate the desired result but I'm not sure that the math is sound!

In  his solution to the original post, [Henry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618636/generate-sample-from-poisson-distribution-with-fixed-sum/618639#618639) used a multinomial to simulate [image] random counts from a Poisson distrubution which sum to [image]. The method involves sampling uniformly [image] times with replacement from [image] and counting how many times each of the [image] values is selected. Code pasted below for convenience:

```
set.seed(10)
y <- 10000
n <- 250
x <- table(factor(sample(n, y, replace=TRUE), levels=1:n))
hist(x)
```

We can show that the result sums to y and approximates a Poisson distribution with mean = variance = [image] = 40.

```
sum(x)  #10000
mean(x) #40
var(x)  #38.4
```

In the Poisson case, each of the [image] values are sampled with equal probability. To generate data from a negative binomial distribution instead we need to increase the variance in x according to the size or theta parameter ([image]), which we can achieve by introducing variation in the sampling probilities.

According to Venables & Ripley (2002), Modern Applied Statistics with S: 'Theta' defines a gamma distribution with shape [image] & scale [image: mu]. So, for a negative binomial distribution with [image], we can generate [image] random draws from the relevant gamma distribution and use these as the sampling probabilites in `sample`.

```
theta = 10
w = rgamma(n,shape=theta,scale=1/theta)
x = table(factor(sample(n, y, replace=TRUE,prob=w), levels=1:n)) 
hist(x)
```

The result sums to [image] and has mean = [image], but the variance is substantially increased and approximates the thereotical expecation of [image] for a negative binomial distribution:

```
mean(x)  # 40
var(x)   # 239.5

# Expected variance
mu = y/n
mu + mu^2/theta   # 200
```

The theta parameter estimated from the samples using [image] is also approximately right

```
mean(x)^2/(var(x)-mean(x)) # 8
```

As theta increases to large numbers the sampling probabilities (*w*) returned by `rgamma` become uniformly 1 and the distribution converges to the original Poisson

```
theta = 1E6
w = rgamma(n,shape=theta,scale=1/theta)
x = table(factor(sample(n, y, replace=TRUE,prob=w), levels=1:n)) 
hist(x)
mean(x)
var(x)
```

Comment: I doubt that the solution is that simple. Although it is correct, that the negative binomial distribution can be seen as a Gamma-Poisson mixture, I think the situation is a bit more tricky here. If I want to generate $n$ independent negative binomial RVs, I can simply start with $n$ independent Gamma RVs and then simulate Poisson RVs. However, if I condition on the sum being fixed, it is not clear to me that the Poisson parameters are again i.i.d. Gamma variables. Conditioning will change the distribution and I'm not sure how.